Connection of Protective Earth in EVs
I am new to this forum and this is my first question.
I am reading about the Electric Vehicle and their charging.
I went through this link - J1772, where the connector image is displayed.
The connector has a PE terminal.
Going through a lot of material and links, I read that the Protective Earth is connected to a earth rod on the charging station side.

So, this earth rod will be connected to the metal case of the charging box also, right?

On the vehicle side, where does this Protective Earth get connected to?
2. Will this protective earth be connected to the Chassis of the car?

Is the purpose of this PE just similar to the Earth for other general electrical appliances?



Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Duplicate from before migration: Connection of Protective Earth for EV charging

Adding your general location will help.  We assume this is for the UK, but different locations/countries have different codes/electrical systems.  What is right for the UK is wrong for NA.

The point of PE (Protective Earth) is to ensure that any conductive surface you can touch will be at the same potential, so that no current will pass through you - but rather through PE conductor if a fault occurs.
That means that the metal of the car, the metal shell of the charger, and so forth should be connected to PE. In many locations it will include a connection to water pipes and rebar in concrete.
In general house installations the only ground (or earth) is PE, so usually we simply say earth or ground, not PE specifically. In more complex installations you may have more earths, for instance a signal earth, so that PE has to be specified - because they serve different purposes.

The UK has some fairly bizarre ideas, including using derived earth ground. This seems to be based on worrying about closely adjacent buildings communicating short circuits through the respective grounding rods being too close. In turn this leads to other potential safety issues.
